# The desciption meta tag is not showing in a Google organic listing

Tags: html, meta-tags, google-search

I have realised the `desciption` meta tag is not showing in a Google organic listing on a new site.

Please see below the meta tags. I have always used these tags before without a problem. I have double checked the code and researched the correct syntax but can't see what is wrong. I also used a spider simulator at Webconfes and it saw the description tag.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<base href="//www.executivehealthsydney.com.au/"/>
<title>Complete Health Checks forBbusy Executives by Doctors</title>
<meta name="description" content="Sydney Medical clinic provides ongoing health service with Doctors and in office visits for vaccinations and blood tests. Call for an Appointmen..." />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Complete Health Checks, Exams, Examinatin, Executives, Pyrmont, Sydney, Medical clinic, vaccinations, blood tests, insurance" />
<!-- [if lt IE9] > <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> <! [end if] --> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/client.ico?"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=.9, minimum-scale=.9" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link  href="/157e96e9df89f4f44312c0e13933810cmaster/template/controller/stylecontroller/css_loader.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link  href="/157e96e9df89f4f44312c0e13933810ciceblue/template/view/style/template.php " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/40c3e1fb2a9f1519165184d1b9c796fb/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/system/deploy/library/scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Google Search only shows the `meta`-`description` if it thinks it’s useful in that context (which might depend on various factors like query, user, previous searches etc.).

From [Google’s documentation **Review your page titles and snippets**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en) (bold emphasis mine):

> Google will **sometimes** use the meta description of a page in search results snippets, **if we think** it gives users a more accurate description than would be possible purely from the on-page content.

Comment: thanks but I have read this page previously, Is it true google snippets only work for certain content though, not general text content?

Comment: @char: Sorry, I don’t understand what you mean. What is "general text content", and why should Google *not* show a snippet for such results?