# Better webpage Descriptions in Google search results possible using Schema?

Tags: meta-tags, schema.org, jsonschema, google-schemas, json-ld

I've successfully used the JSON-LD implementation of Google Schemas to make information in Google search results more detailed and meaningful.  More specifically, I am able to get Google search results to display a company logo and company description by adding the pertinent JSON-LD code to the top page of my site. Details here:

https://developers.google.com/schemas/formats/json-ld

I now want better text descriptions to display in Google search results for individual web pages in my sites.  The reason is because Google is not picking up the **META Description tag** data on some web pages and instead grabs some text on the page that is not descriptive, helpful or meaningful.  **I would like to know if I can work around that problem using Google Schema?**

At https://schema.org one can review the various categories available, but it is not clear how we are to mark individual web pages with the aim of merely describing the individual page itself.  **Is Google Schema not intended for web page descriptions?  If it can be used for that, what is the proper categorization?**

For those of you who don't fully understand what I mean, Google "**google**". The search results will show this:

```
    Google
    www.google.com/
    Company description...

       Google Maps
       Short page description...

       Google News
       Short page description...

       and so on.
```

My aim is to fix those "Short page descriptions" for some individual pages in my sites.  And again, the presence of a properly constructed DESCRIPTION meta tag is not a solution for some reason.  I would like to know if Google Schemas can be a fix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There exists http://schema.org/WebPage which you can use for this. AFAICT from [Google's Structured Data documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/) such markup isn't used though.

Comment: @unor @Markus The following structure validates on the Structured Data Testing Tool:

`<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "name": "name of web page",
    "description": "same content as Description meta tag"
}
</script>`

So I will add that to a page, give it a month or too, and see what happens in the Google Search results.

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate property from Schema.org would be [`description`](http://schema.org/description), which can be used on any type (in your case you’d probably want to use it on [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage)).

However, neither does Google document to make use of it, nor does it seem likely that they would handle it differently than `meta`-`description`, which [they only use if they deem it useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574278/1591669).