# HTML meta tag not changing description snippet in search engines (Google/Bing)

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags, google-search, bing

I have a Laravel site. When you search for my site on search engines, the "description" snippet of my site doesn't show up. Instead, it simply takes some of the first user generated text it parses. Like so:

[image]

But of course I'd rather the description I use in the `<meta name="description"` tag to show up, rather than that.

For reference, this is the start of my site's `<head>`:

```html
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<meta name="description" content="The Art Freelance Community - Buy & Sell Art"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="art, artist, commission, contract, freelance, find artist, hire artist">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This `description` meta tag isn't a recent addition either, so I'm confused as to why it's not using it.

Comment: there's unclosed tags?

Comment: [The desciption meta tag is not showing in a Google organic listing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28573152/1591669)

Comment: @M.Aroosi — The end tag for meta elements is forbidden in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Have you submitted your URL using Google Search Console ?
You should know that Google does not always respect the description defined on the web page. However, I advise you to place a description of about 230 characters.